# Search collection fields and populated fields at the same time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have 2 collections as the following:

```
Products
 - name (String)
 - price (number)
 - category (ObjectID refs to Category collection)

Category
- name
```

And we have search query for example "some query"

I'm trying to get the records where **product.name** or **product.category.name** *partially* includes the search query

Comment: Perhaps using a $text index will work: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/

Comment: Text index doesn't work with a populated field.
Also, it searches for an exact match, it doesn't support partial search @ScottGnile

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mongoose populate, that uses DBRef, which is not easily used on the server side.

If the Products document contains only the _id of the corresponding Category document, you would need to use aggregation to read all Products documents, and for each one load all of the corresponding Category documents, then filter using a regular expression.

That is not scalable.

If you denormalize a little bit by having the Products document contain both the _id and name of the Category (assuming Category actually has other data), you could use a text index on the Products collection, or if you are using Atlas, full text search in the Products collection.

Comment: I believe the most relevant solution adding the category name with the _id in the product’s collection but still text index doesn’t search partially

Comment: MongoDB's text search does not do substring matches, it uses language-dependent rules to match base words.  A search for "jumped" would match a string containing any of  "jump", "jumped","jumping",or "jumps" as separate words, but would not match  "outjump".  If you need a substring match, you'll need to use a regex.